# How to use javascript export keyword in browser or console

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

[**export**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) keyword is introduced in ecmascript5:

```
var myFunc1 = function() { console.log('hello'); };   
export.myFunc1 = myFunc1;
```

If I run above code in firefox console it gives error:

```
SyntaxError: missing declaration after 'export' keyword  
export.myFunc1 = myFunc1;
```

I don't understand what I need to declare.

Am I using it in the wrong way?

Any advice would be nice!

Comment: What did you expect that code to do? Where did you learn that the `export` keyword is used that way? The w3schools page you link to only says that it's reserved in ES5, nothing else.

Comment: 1: i expect to know what that keyword does in javascript and how to use it in any way also kept nodejs **exports** with **s** keyword in mind and tried the above code in browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The syntax for ES6 `export` looks like this](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html):

```
//------ lib.js ------
export const sqrt = Math.sqrt;
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
export function diag(x, y) {
    return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
}

//------ main.js ------
import { square, diag } from 'lib';
console.log(square(11)); // 121
console.log(diag(4, 3)); // 5
```

Note that this is different from the CommonJS `modules.export` syntax used in Node.js.

Comment: To add a bit to what @Trott is saying, you can also find the export syntax in the ECMAScript (6) Specification section 15.2.3 (download the PDF or DOC from here: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts#final_draft )

Comment: @Trott  looks like my browser firefox 37 dosen't  have ecmascript6 . i kept those 2 files in html file and fired .still it gives error  : `missing declaration after 'export' keyword` And  `SyntaxError: modules are not implemented yet`

Comment: also [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export]( mozilla export) says that it will be available in ecmascript 6

Answer (score 0):

Node js uses `exports` to expose functionality in modules to their implementers

defined here. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports

Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably because it completely ignored what the OP is asking about,  e.g., the browser console part.

Comment: also in nodejs it is **exports** with **s** And In javascript it is just **export** it took time for me to see this spelling